# web api 2 versioning using attribute routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having a problem using Attribute Routing where the compiler is showing the error "Type 'ValuesController' already defines a member called 'Get' with the same parameter types".

I have checked that config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes() is in the webapiConfig file

```
    // GET api/values/5
    [Route("api/values/{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    [Route("api/v2/values/{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
```

From reading http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2 something like this should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is invalid C#, even aside from Web API. You can't define the same function signature twice. If you rename the second `Get` to `GetNew`, or move it to a different controller, it should work.

Comment: I change the 2nd Get to GetV2 and that works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as I see it, is that you have two methods with the same name and arguments, which isn't allowed in C# - if you really must have the same method names, you need to overload on the number of arguments, and/or their types:

```
public string Get(int id, int id2)
```

Or

```
public string Get(Guid id)
```